problem with styling flutter_slidable package
i want to achieve a design like this with my slidable tile : (https://i.sstatic.net/z1O7Xgt5.png)(https://i.sstatic.net/2fZvPbaM.png)
for now it looks like this where the border radius isnt matching: (https://i.sstatic.net/gw1Xlp2I.png)
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';

class HabitTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String habitName;
  final bool habitCompleted;
  final Function(bool?)? onChanged;
  final Function(BuildContext)? settingsTapped;
  final Function(BuildContext)? deleteTapped;
  const HabitTile({
    super.key,
    required this.habitName,
    required this.habitCompleted,
    this.onChanged,
    this.settingsTapped,
    this.deleteTapped,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
      child: Slidable(
        startActionPane: ActionPane(
          extentRatio: 0.2,
          motion: const StretchMotion(),
          children: [
            SlidableAction(
              onPressed: (context) {
                if (onChanged != null) {
                  onChanged!(!habitCompleted); // Toggle habitCompleted
                }
              },
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              icon: Icons.check,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        endActionPane: ActionPane(
          extentRatio: 0.4,
          motion: const StretchMotion(),
          children: [
            // settings option
            SlidableAction(
              onPressed: settingsTapped,
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
              icon: Icons.settings,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),

            // delete option
            SlidableAction(
              onPressed: deleteTapped,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade400,
              icon: Icons.delete,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[100],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Text(habitName),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


this is my code for now ,is there a solution i can do , or other package you suggest?
